# "Sequence generated" Is Not Shown to be in Order? Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image: execute_query applied to show all records, sequence works fine but not in descending order]
execute_query applied to show all records, sequence works fine but not in descending order

please help if there's any way to order this data block by the sequence in ("No", column)

```
create table Citizens_lic
(
No          NUMBER(10)              ,
ID          NUMBER(10)    
constraint      Citizens_ID_pk_1     PRIMARY KEY,
F_Name                  VARCHAR2(32)            ,
M_Name                  VARCHAR2(32)            ,
L_Name                  VARCHAR2(32)            ,
DOB                     DATE                    ,
POB                     VARCHAR2(32)            ,
GENDER                  VARCHAR2(32)            ,
WORK_STATUS             VARCHAR2(32)        ,
Soc_status              VARCHAR2(32)            ,
ISS_DATE                date                    ,
EXP_Date                date                   
)
```

this is the table, here is the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CITIZENS_LIC_NO_SEQ_1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
```

here is the trigger:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CITIZENS_LIC_NO_TRIGG_1
 BEFORE INSERT ON CITIZENS_LIC
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 SELECT CITIZENS_LIC_NO_SEQ_1.NEXTVAL
 INTO   :new.NO
 FROM   DUAL;
 END;
```

try to add any value, it will work fine, but when you add values from the forms builder, it will change the order according to your mouse click

another matter is when I try to delete anything from the table,
the sequence ruined the order and the deleted value disappeared with its sequence number forever!

[image: might triggers help but I don't know which one is good to use]

might forms' trigger help but I don't know which one is good to use

Comment: Please don't use pictures to describe your code and/or data; not all of us can see the images through our firewalls, and it makes the code and data difficult to copy and paste!

Comment: um, sorry, editing the question :)

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that sequences don't guarantee order - for example, on RAC databases, it's likely you will get sequences added out of order. Far better is to have a date or timestamp column that stores the date at the time the row was inserted. Note that this won't tell you when the row was committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort rows in a data block, open its properties palette, find `ORDER BY` property and put whatever you want in there. In your case, it seems that it would be

```
order by no desc
```

When you execute a query in that data block, the result will be sorted by the `no` column in descending order.

As of **deleting** rows: of course, it will be lost. What did you expect? Sequences guarantee unique, but not gapless list of numbers. Mind its cache; you don't even have to delete any rows, but two consecutive sessions might produce gaps. That's how sequences work; I'd just accept it, if I were you.

If you want to create gapless numbers, you'll have to write your own code and it won't be as simple as you think. You'll have to pay attention to inserts (which is simple), updates and deletes. Once again: stick to sequences.